# Get PID by parsing the output of /bin/ps

Tags: c, pid

Within a C-program I'm reading line by line the output of /bin/ps -fu1000 and searching for a string, for example "gnome".
When I found the string (gnome), how can I get the pid?
The whole line is saved in a char buf[256].

```
cm       12556     1  0 10:47 ?        00:00:13 gnome-terminal
```

... and yes it's part of a homework.

---

After reading some comments:

I had to use C. Goal of the task is to write a program which will send signals to running processes, containing a specified string in its name.

My approach is like:

```
fp = popen("/bin/ps -fu1000", "r");
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)){
  if(strstr(line, "gnome")){
    printf("found\n");
    /* do some nice stuff to get the PID */
  }
}
```

Comment: does the homework specify that you need to parse `ps` or what that your solution the problem you're trying to solve ?

Comment: If you trust the input, `scanf` might be an idea. It mostly "ignores" whitespace and, with a `*` in a conversion specifier can ignore fields

Comment: Assigning homework to parse human-oriented command line progams' output with C is akin to assigning homework to write an h264 encoder in Perl...

Comment: If the assignment is truly "parse the output of ps -fu", you should drop the class.  If the assignment is to get the pid, then instead of parsing the output of ps -fu parse the output of 'ps -o comm pid | awk '/gnome/{print $2}'.  Solving a problem like this in C is a pointless use of the tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is in C try looking at the `sscanf` standard library function. Documentation should be available through either via a man page on a Unix type system such as Linux, or an online reference such as the [GNU C Reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing space characters with a unique separator. Then search for the PID column jumping from one separator to another.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Linux platform, with regards to your precision, you can iterate through every PID folder in /proc and read the cmdline file. That's basically what ps does.

And by keeping track of the folder you're in, you can then get the pid.